# Spring-boot Thymeleaf Multipart file upload

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create a page that allows a user to select a file to be uploaded to my SpringMVC Controller.

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class CustomerDataController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/customerFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("myFile") MultipartFile file) {
      if ( !file.isEmpty() ) {
          String name = file.getName();
          try {
              byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
               BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( new File( name + "-uploaded" ) ) );
              stream.write( bytes );
              stream.close();
              return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
           catch ( Exception e ) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
           }
      } else {
           return "The selected file was empty and could not be uploaded.";
      }
  }
```

And my upload.html form has:

```
 <form action="upload" th:action="@{/customerFile}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="myFile" />
      <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

I have also tried using a standard (non Thymeleaf form):

```
 <form method="post" action="/customerFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Not sure if it's relevant but I have the following configuration:

```
 @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
       ...
        registry.addViewController( "/upload" ).setViewName( "upload" );
    }

@Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("512KB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("512KB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
```

I have the following in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.0.0.RC4")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.0.RC1")
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.1.Final")
    compile("com.h2database:h2:1.3.172")
    compile("joda-time:joda-time:2.3")
    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
    compile("org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1")
    compile('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.2.1')
    compile('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1')

    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', module: 'groovy-all'
    }
    testCompile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7+')
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

I am running embedded Tomcat, launched via:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ofac = SpringApplication.run( OFAC.class, args );
}
```

When I click the submit button, I don't see a request in my controller but I get a the following in my browser:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'myFile' is not present

type Status report

message Required MultipartFile parameter 'myFile' is not present

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
```

Here is what Firebug tells me about the request:

```
connection  close
Content-Language    en
Content-Length  1080
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Mon, 24 Mar 2014 17:09:55 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=86768954CD2877A7D78535E26CFFB8DA
DNT 1
Host    localhost:9001
Referer http://localhost:9001/upload
```

Comment: You are using `@EnableAutoConfiguration`? Where does the "**message**" come from (doesn't look like what you'd see in a browser)?

Comment: Yes, I am using @EnableAutoConfiguration and the following are in my build.gradle:  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")..compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4").  I updated my error message that is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Are you running from a main() method or in a deployed WAR? Can you share the whole project?

Comment: I am running from a main, but unfortunately the project is too large to share.  I will update the question with my main method.

Comment: It looks to me like form isn't working. Could you try a static HTML file? Or check the rendered source HTML matches what you expect in the browser before submitting the form?

Comment: I replaced my Thymeleaf with a regular html page (see above) and I still get errors.  Could this be the format of the request?  Do I need to set headers or the rest controller to expect/use specific content type since I am expecting a file upload?  Do I need to use a speific sprint-boot-web version since there was an issue with RC4?

Comment: Your dependencies *are* still a bit of a mess. Certainly you should try with Spring Boot snapshots (and rc5).

Comment: Thank you, changing my spring-boot-starter-web to RC5 and the file upload seems to be working correctly now.  My apologies on the dependency confusion, if you can recommend some sources, I will read up and try to get a better understanding.  I have been learning by following along with the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution was to update Spring Boot (a bug in the multipart autoconfig had been fixed so that was probably it).